# SQLAlchemy column_property using another column_property

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy for my discord bot and face a problem.

I have 3 tables (related to the problem):

UserLeveling, Level and User.

Here is the implementation of each one:

```py
class Guild(Base):
    __tablename__ = "guilds"
    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    members: Mapped[List["User"]] = relationship(back_populates="guild")

class ExperienceHistory(Base):
    __tablename__ = "experience_history"
    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_leveling_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users_leveling.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    user_leveling: Mapped["UserLeveling"] = relationship(back_populates="history")
    amount: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=False)


class UserLeveling(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users_leveling"
    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.BigInteger, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), unique=True)
    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(back_populates="leveling")
    history: Mapped[List["ExperienceHistory"]] = relationship(back_populates="user_leveling", lazy="dynamic")
    
    experience = column_property(
        select(func.greatest(func.sum(ExperienceHistory.amount), 0))
        .where(ExperienceHistory.user_leveling_id == id)
        .label("experience")
    )
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint(user_id, name="user_leveling_user_id__uq"),)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    
    # Information
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.BigInteger)
    guild_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.BigInteger, ForeignKey("guilds.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    guild: Mapped["Guild"] = relationship(back_populates="members")
    present: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(default=False)
    
    # Leveling
    leveling: Mapped["UserLeveling"] = relationship(back_populates="user")

    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("id", "guild_id", name="_user_by_guild"),)

class Level(Base):
    __tablename__ = "levels"
    
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    number: Mapped[int] = mapped_column()
    experience: Mapped[int] = mapped_column()
    guild_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.BigInteger, ForeignKey("guilds.id", ondelete="CASCADE"))
    guild: Mapped["Guild"] = relationship()
```

My goal is to add a level entry on UserLeveling which is corresponding to the level of the user.
The Level is the last one to be inferior or equal to the experience of the UserLeveling

Here is what I use to find the actual Level.id corresponding to the good Level :

```py
    min_experience_subquery = (
        select(func.min(Level.experience))
        .where(Level.experience > experience)
        .correlate_except(Level)
        .scalar_subquery()
    )
    
    level = column_property(
        select(Level.id)
        .where(
            and_(
                Level.experience == min_experience_subquery,
                Level.guild_id == User.guild_id
            )
        )
        .correlate_except(Level)
        .scalar_subquery()
    )
```

but what I want is the Level object instead of the id. I want to be able to use UserLeveling.level, any way to do that?

Thanks for the help

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)